How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the pair of equations $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_7 = 37$ and $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6$ together?
How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the pair of equations together?

$x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_7 = 37 $

and

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6 $

I've done the work to calculate c(8,2) * c(34,3). I just wanted to verify if this would be the solution for the amount of total solutions or if this would be the solution for the amount of nonnegative solutions. If it's the former, I would appreciate if anyone had any advice on how to work towards the nonnegative solutions. Thanks :)
Work for the above result:

c(6+3-1,3-1) = c(8,2)


37-6 = 31 to account for what we've already found


c(31+6-3,6-3) = c(34,3)


Please include how you found this result, and where your doubts are.

The answer is already here

Thank you for the link! I also provided the work I did to compute my result. My only doubt was whether this was the final result for all solutions or if I needed to do something else to get only the nonnegative solutions

For $(k,n)\in\mathbb{N}^*\times\mathbb{N}$, define $a_{k,n}=card((x_1,...,x_k)\in\mathbb{N}^k| x_1+...+x_k=n)$.
For example, for any natural integer $n$, $a_{1,n}=1$ and $a_{2,n}=n+1$
We're looking for $a_{3,6}\times a_{4,31}$.
Now for any $(k,n)\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\begin{array}{ccl}
a_{k+1,n}&=&card((x_1,...,x_k,x_{k+1})\in\mathbb{N}^{k+1}| x_1+...+x_{k+1}=n)\\
&=&\cup_{d=0}^n card((x_1,...,x_k)\in\mathbb{N}^d|x_1+...+x_k=n-d)\\
&=&\sum_{d=0}^na_{k,n-d}\end{array}$$
By induction, $$a_{k,n}=\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$
Conclusion : the number of solutions is $\binom{6+3-1}{3-1}\binom{31+4-1}{4-1}=167552$.

Thank you so much for the verification on this! I appreciate it :)
